# Why do I still get the "module not found" error even after having installed the package using pip install?

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to create an image processing program using convolutions. I need the package scikit-image, specifically this:

`from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity`

I have repeatedly installed scikit-image using `pip install scikit-image` in my **terminal (Mac)**. I did this in the folder where my **convolutions.py** file is located (is this what is meant by the **PYTHONPATH**?). However, I always get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Convolutions.py", line 6, in <module>
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
ImportError: No module named skimage.exposure
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: have you added pip to path? if you havnt then the install might not work

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are installing the package on the same version of python which you are running. On a mac, `python` by default runs python-2.7, and the command `python3` runs python-3.x. Also, `pip` by default installs packages to python-2.7. To install them on python3 try running

```
python3 -m pip install scikit-image
```

or simply

```
pip3 install scikit-image
```